# Как правильно пишется слово "текст" во множественном числе?

Tags: морфология

Как правильно пишется слово "текст" во множественном числе: "тексты" ли "текста"?

Comment: Текст**а**? По аналогии со средств**а**ми? Хе-хе.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется, "тексты". Окончание "-а" допустимо только в профессиональном сленге и в названии профессий (опять же как сленг). Но в остальных случаях - исключительно "-ы".

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно, "тексты"